# How to make a SQL Server database portable and modifiable between different users?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

Me and my friends are working on a desktop application that requires a database. I was able to create the database and modify it on both my laptop and my desktop. We are using Github for source control, after they pull the code (including the database) and try to run it it shows an error that the data base wasn't found. To be exact it shows an error with the path of the database on my computer like: `C:\Users\myname\repofolder\databasename.mdf`. Is there anyway that they can modify the database themselves so we can all be working on it at the same time?

Thanks.

Comment: How about deploy it on new Database server ? Or you and your friend are in the same network ?

Comment: Put the connection string in config ....

Comment: @zey Sorry, I didn't really get what you're saying. Could you explain what you mean exactly by saying deploy it on a new Database server?

Comment: Are you and your friend in the same network ?

Comment: Ok , I think Google Cloud sql may help you  >  https://cloud.google.com/sql/